# How can unexpected '{' error in if condition be fixed in PHP?

Tags: php

my php code is

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["userId"]){
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

and i got an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\page\login.php on line 3
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you forgot a closing bracket `)` before the opening curly bracket `{`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["userId"])){
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

When you get an unexpected character syntax error in PHP, it's usually because there is a character missing right before it

Comment: thank you for answers it's was just a silly mistake